# Can we use Power automate to automate creating new users inside Office 365 and assign them list of groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, powerapp, azure-active-directory

I received a request to create a Power Automate flow for HR managers as follow:

- The HR Manager will add the user name inside a SharePoint list >> then the flow will automatically start
- The flow will import all the email groups from Azure Ad and show them to the user.
- The flow will allow the user to chose what groups they want the user to be part of
- The flow will allow the user to choose the user work location from a list
- The flow will allow the user to choose the user role
- The flow will allow the user to choose the user manager
- Then the flow will create the user automatically on the local AD

Can we create such as workflow inside power automate ?

Comment: You will need user interface for selecting location/role/manager, etc. So, I think you need to develop a Power App for this requirement. Only Power app or Power App + Power Automate solution.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you advice more on this please? how i can use Power app to do so.. so you mean i can select the Groups, locations, roles and managers using power automate then populate those values inside power app forms? but where i will be storing the values for locations, roles, managers and groups?

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you advice more on this please? how i can use Power app to do so.. so you mean i can select the Groups, locations, roles and managers using power automate then populate those values inside power app forms? but where i will be storing the values for locations, roles, managers and groups?

Comment: You want your users to choose the groups/locations/roles/managers fetched dynamically from Azure AD. In order to choose these fields, user will require the user interface which is not possible by using Power Automate only. So, you have two options: 1. SPFx web part (developer experience required) 2. Power App (faster/low code solution). & If you want to store the user selections for groups/locations/roles/managers, you can store those in SharePoint lists.

Comment: @GaneshSanap but what other options i have if i will not store the groups/locations/roles/managers inside SharePoint lists? can i for example using power automate to dynamically populate the groups/locations/roles/managers inside power app without storing them inside SharePoint?

Comment: @GaneshSanap but what other options i have if i will not store the groups/locations/roles/managers inside SharePoint lists? can i for example using power automate to dynamically populate the groups/locations/roles/managers inside power app without storing them inside SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, you can show options for groups/locations/roles/managers in power apps (dropdown/combo-box or any other supported controls). Even you might be able to call AD connector methods in Power apps & bring the data in your app if the connector is supported in power apps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks again for your help ..so let me summarize what we will be doing.. Create PowerApp >> connect it to Azure AD to get all the Manager/locations/roles/groups and populate different lists inside power app >> then when the user save the power app form>> power automate will create the new user based on the data inside the power app form.. is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Here's documentation of connectors available: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/

Answer (score 1):

You want your users to choose from the groups/locations/roles/managers fetched dynamically from Azure AD.

In order to choose the options from these fields, user will require the user interface which is not possible by using Power Automate only.

So, you have two options:

1. SPFx web part (developer experience required)
2. Power App (faster/low code solution).

If you want to store the user selections for groups/locations/roles/managers, you can store those in SharePoint lists.

Below are the rough steps you need to perform:

1. Create Power App
2. Connect it to Azure AD to get all the Manager/locations/roles/groups and populate different controls inside power app form
3. When the user saves the power app form, power automate (or power app functions if possible) will create the new user based on the data inside the power app form

Here's documentation of connectors available: [Connector reference overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/)

Comment: Hi @john Gu , Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.